# Can tmux display pretty pane corners?

Tags: terminal, colors, tmux

I'm in the process of picking up tmux, and I'm sure I'll get used to it, but this pointy edge is bothersome.

[image]

Is there a way to make the corner flush, like this (fixed with gimp)?

[image]

I know that the appropriate ANSI characters exist, but my searches for how to add them to tmux have come up empty.  Is there a way to configure tmux to apply the right ANSI character to pane border corners, based on the active pane?